# How to write file into another

Tags: files, dd

I have an empty file (only zeroes are in it) of size 9,0KB and I need to write another file (with size 1,1KB) to it, but the first file must not lose its size or the rest of its contents. So if the whole file is `00000000000000...` now, I need to write second file in it and leave the zeroes as they are. I have tried to use `dd`, but I haven't succeed - file resizes.

```
dd if=out/one.img of=out/go.img
```

Does anybody know how can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To overwrite the start of the destination file without truncating it, give the `notrunc` conversion directive:

```
$ dd if=out/one.img of=out/go.img conv=notrunc
```

If you wanted the source file's data *appended* to the destination, you can do that with the `seek` directive:

```
$ dd if=out/one.img of=out/go.img bs=1k seek=9
```

This tells `dd` that the block size is 1 kiB, so that the `seek` goes forward by 9 kiB before doing the write.

You can also combine the two forms. For example, to overwrite the *second* 1 kiB block in the file with a 1 kiB source:

```
$ dd if=out/one.img of=out/go.img bs=1k seek=9 conv=notrunc
```

That is, it skips the first 1 kiB of the output file, overwrites data it finds there with data from the input file, then closes the output without truncating it first.

Comment: I don't want to append. I want to rewrite beginning of the file(first 1,1KB) and leave other zeroes filling file to 9KB be.

Comment: Finally found your point, I have edited it...

Answer (score 5):

Just open the target file in read-write mode with the `<>` shell redirection operator instead of write-only with truncation with `>`:

Assuming you want to write `file2` on top of `file1`:

```
cat file2 1<> file1
```

That would write `file2` into `file1` at offset 0 (at the beginning).

If you want to append `file2` at the end of `file1`, use the `>>` operator.

```
cat file2 >> file1
```

You can also write `file2` at any offset within `file1` with:

```
{ head -c1000 # for 1000 bytes within or
  # head -n 10 # for 10 lines within
  cat file2 >&0
} <> file1 > /dev/null
```

Though for byte offsets, you'll probably find using Warren's `dd` solutions to be more convenient.